# Webrick and mysqld.exe on Windows hanging

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

I have a Windows Sever 2008 development environment with Ruby 1.9.3 and MySQL 5.6.  This has been running fine until this week when any calls from Webrick to the SQL server cause Webrick to hang and mysqld.exe to sit constantly consuming 25% of the server's CPU.  Stopping mysqld service allows Webrick to recover but the problem persists. I can run queries direct from MySQL Workbench and my rspec tests which include SQL calls also run.  What can I do to investigate the problem?

Comment: You want to look at the last entry in the logs first. Webrick is single-threaded, so last lines of the log file will give you a solid clue what was the last thing to happen before it hung.

Comment: The logs weren't very helpful - but I've just realised if I stop the mysqld service I can see that it was trying to query a table called Changerequests for 187515.6ms!  I ran mysqlcheck but it said all tables were OK.  I also tried installing Thin, and this encounters the same problem...

Comment: Well, sounds like it was a transaction, so no reason to think tables would be corrupted (unless you were using some really fancy configuration, but you'd know that). Did you find what SQL was being executed at the time?

Comment: Oh hold on.  It's joined to a view and that view doesn't appear to be running in a reasonable amount of time according to MySQL.  So this clearly isn't related to the webserver at all.

Comment: Yep - I think it was that view, so this was not MySQL or the server. my bad